# Qt5: toLongLong fails

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I'm trying to convert a `QByteArray` that contains a value in hex format to `long long`:

```
QByteArray field = "A8BC301F0193E83F";
bool ok;
qlonglong val = field.toLongLong(&ok, 16);
qDebug() << ok << val;
```

output:

> false 0

Instead I'm expecting val = -6.288.098.069.987.465.153.

Why it fails? The docs says nothing about any limitation of this function.

I forgot to mention the data order is little endian in the source.

Comment: To get the expected output you need to write it like `QByteArray field = "-5743CFE0FE6C17C1";`, no? Your `A8BC301F0193E83F` number represents hex signed twos complement of that number, though.

Comment: The "field" variable should contain the bit representation of the number. Is the conversion that should take care of the sign (if any). Am I wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Your number exceeds the limits of a `signed long long`, so conversion fails.

You can use [`QByteArray::toULongLong`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qbytearray.html#toULongLong) instead and then make a cast to `long long`.

```
#include <qbytearray.h>
#include <qdebug.h>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  QByteArray field = "A8BC301F0193E83F";
  bool ok;
  qlonglong val = field.toLongLong(&ok, 16);
  qDebug() << ok << val;

  qulonglongval_u = field.toULongLong(&ok, 16);
  qDebug() << ok << val_u << (long long)val_u;

  long long check = 0xA8BC301F0193E83F;
  qDebug() << check;

  return 0;
}
```

---

EDIT: you can take a look at the [source code](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/corelib/tools/qbytearray.cpp.html#_ZL17toIntegral_helperPKcPbi) of the associated helper function and see that this is indeed the case between signed and unsigned integers.

Answer (score 1):

You can find the final function Qt call to convert `ByteArray` to `long long` here [qlocale.cpp](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/radekp/qt/b881d8fb99972f1bd04ab4c84843cc8d43ddbeed/src/corelib/tools/qlocale.cpp) in function `static qlonglong qstrtoll`

It defines 
`cutoff = neg ? qulonglong(0-(LLONG_MIN + LLONG_MAX)) + LLONG_MAX : LLONG_MAX;`.

So `cutoff` will be `0x8000000000000000` if `neg`, or will be `0x7fffffffffffffff` if non `neg`.

Your input value is bigger than `cutoff` so it returns `false`.

You can get the `static qlonglong qstrtoll` function and debug by your own.